# jQuery - Find CSS bottom of div at start, not during animation on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm finding the CSS value 'bottom' for each of these divs with the class of 'shelf-info-text'. Each of these divs are inside shelf-item.

The bottom value is automatically calculated using another function. On hover I wish bottom to be changed to 0px by way of animation, and then revert to the original bottom. Bottom will be different for every single div.

I have added a little code to find the bottom, however if you hover again mid-animation this finds the bottom before it has returned back to the original state, therefore breaking the animation.

Please advise where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

```
var $itemBottom = null;
$('.shelf-item').hover(function() {
    $itemBottom = $(this).find('.shelf-info-text').css('bottom');
    $(this).find('.shelf-info-text').stop().animate({ 'bottom': '0px'}, 300);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.shelf-info-text').stop().animate({ 'bottom': $itemBottom}, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit :
After re-reading the question here's a solution that will get the bottom and save it in a data attribute.

```
// we loop through all the shelf items and set a data attribute to keep track of it.
$('.shelf-item').each(function(){
    $item = $(this).find('.shelf-info-text');
    $itemBottom = $item.css('bottom');
    $item.data('bottom', $itemBottom);
});

$('.shelf-item').hover(function() {
    $itemBottom = $(this).find('.shelf-info-text').data('bottom');
    $(this).find('.shelf-info-text').stop().animate({ 'bottom': '0px'}, 300);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.shelf-info-text').stop().animate({ 'bottom': $itemBottom}, 300);
});
```

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what I'm looking for. The animation is working perfectly, it's just finding the bottom value when it shouldn't. Ideally, I'd like it to find this value on page load, and never again, storing this. I don't know how working that into a (this) would work, however.

Comment: @JakeHills could you add your markup to a fiddle? P.s: i think i got what you are looking for and might have a solution, gimme a moment to type it up.

Comment: PERFECT! I was half way through a fiddle but never mind - thanks so much :)

Comment: @JakeHills my pleasure ^^

Answer (score 1):

I'm too late to the party (because I got distracted making [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ra5SK/2/)). My approach is the same as @Patsy's but I avoid the `.each()` loop to set the `data-bottom` by simply setting it if it doesn't already exist:

```
var $el = null;
$('.shelf-item').hover(function() {
    $el = $(this).find('.shelf-info-text');
    $el.data('bottom',($el.data('bottom') || $el.css('bottom'))).stop().animate({ 'bottom': '0px'}, 300);
}, function() {
    $el = $(this).find('.shelf-info-text');
    $el.stop().animate({ 'bottom': $el.data('bottom')}, 300);
});
```

Comment: A little late yes..  but giving you +1 for working example - cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the original bottom value using [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).  Then your function could check to see if that value had been stored, and never recalculate the bottom (avoiding the mid-animation issue).

Comment: Exactly what i was typing :D